# Cordova admob plugin, new google play services SDK

Tags: android, cordova, admob, google-play-services

I'm using this plugin with my phonegap/cordova (version 3.4) android app: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

Recently (8 days ago) I noted that the autor updated to the new google play service sdk instead of the old admob sdk, so I'm trying to use this new sdk. I already installed the lib to my project and all is working and compiling. But when I run the plugin example code, or just this:

> ```
>     window.plugins.AdMob.createBannerView( 
>         {
>         'publisherId' : '...............',
>         'adSize' : am.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
>         'bannerAtTop' : true
>         }, 
>         function() {}, 
>         function() {}
>     );
> ```

The app crashes with this error: "03-06 20:40:20.063: A/libc(6949): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000223 (code=0), thread 6949"

If i just remove that function the page loads well.. Anyone knows what's happening or already get it working with the new sdk?

EDIT: I decided to do myself without plugins. This code works and the ads is already showing. Does this seem correct and its all that is needed to new framework?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")

    // Set ad settings
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    // Layout
    LinearLayout layout = super.root;
    layout.addView(adView); 

    // Request and show ad
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(request);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.resume();
  }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.pause();
  }
  super.onPause();
}

/** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  // Destroy the AdView.
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.destroy();
  }
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Trick: For use this code to show ads without plugins, You must use cordova for create the project, not phonegap. I lost 4 days searching the solution because with this same code didn't work and it don't show ads, but the ads were loading fine.

Comment: I am trying to add this same plugin to my application. Have you had any luck?

Comment: @Sangar82 Can you explain what you mean by building the project with Cordova instead of PhoneGap?

Comment: @Bacon2305 Use this package https://www.npmjs.org/package/cordova to create the project instead of Phonegap cli

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

1. Install the plugin you referred:
   https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob.git
2. Use Cordova 3.3 or 3.5+, as known, v3.4 has some defects fixed in 3.5

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647417/admob-plugins-compatible-with-phonegap-3-4